# Probably client server encryption mismatch

Tags: encryption, aes

The server encrypts a password using the following criteria:

```
AES.HashAlgorithm.MD5,
password = "dynamicweb",                   
salt="dwapac2015",                   
iteration=2,                              
Key size=AES.KeySize.Key192,             
Initial Vector="dwdevelopmentsmm");
```

The server langauge is C#.

On the client side, the same encryption is done as follows:

```
public class Aes {
    private static final String KEY_FACTORY_ALGORITHM = "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1";
    private static final String KEY_SPEC_ALGORITHM = "AES";
    private static final int KEY_LENGTH = 192;
    private static final int KEY_ITERATION_COUNT = 2;

    public static String key  = "dynamicweb";
    public static String salt = "dwapac2015";
    public static String cipherTransformation = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";
    public static String initializationVector = "dwdevelopmentsmm";

    public static String encrypt(String payload) throws Exception {
        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(KEY_FACTORY_ALGORITHM);
        KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(key.toCharArray(), salt.getBytes(), KEY_ITERATION_COUNT, KEY_LENGTH);
        SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(factory.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded(), KEY_SPEC_ALGORITHM);

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(cipherTransformation);

        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret, new IvParameterSpec(initializationVector.getBytes()));

        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(payload.getBytes());
        return new String(Base64.encodeBase64(encrypted));
    }
}
```

The client language is Java.

The server returns the following error:

```
[Authenticate: 11/4/2015 6:42:09 AM]: [REQUEST: {UserName:BPlMi6RfvvWjntEW9Aw5Rw==,Password:BPlMi6RfvvWjntEW9Aw5Rw==}] System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Padding is invalid and cannot be removed. at RestService.ServiceInterface.Helpers.DWCredentialsAuthProvider.CheckInDW(String userName, String password, Int32& currentUserID) at RestService.ServiceInterface.Helpers.DWCredentialsAuthProvider.TryAuthenticate(IServiceBase authService, String userName, String password) at ServiceStack.Auth.CredentialsAuthProvider.Authenticate(IServiceBase authService, IAuthSession session, String userName, String password, String referrerUrl) at ServiceStack.Auth.CredentialsAuthProvider.Authenticate(IServiceBase authService, IAuthSession session, Authenticate request) at ServiceStack.Auth.AuthenticateService.Authenticate(Authenticate request, String provider, IAuthSession session, IAuthProvider oAuthConfig) at ServiceStack.Auth.AuthenticateService.Post(Authenticate request) at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object ) at ServiceStack.Host.ServiceRunner`1.Execute(IRequest request, Object instance, TRequest requestDto)"
```

Comment: They wanted me to encrypt the data that way. Not my idea.

Comment: Then ask for a proper spec of what the server does. I also want to note that this is about as secure as ROT13.

Comment: They will probably switch to TLS later but they still want me to encrypt the data. The thing is they can give me the server code but I'll still have the problem if I don't understand how C# does PBE.